# How many 4 digit numbers can be formed?

Tags: permutations

Given digits: 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8 and 9

1.How many 4-digit numbers can be formed greater than 3000 without repetition?
[Here we mean no repetitive digits]

My answer is 5*7*6*5

2. .How many 4-digit even numbers can be formed greater than 3000 without repetition?

My answer is sum of 2*6*5*4 and 3*6*5*4.

3. Why should we not just divide the answer in no.1 by two to get the answer in no.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) correct. 2) it must be $2\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot \color{red}{3}+3\cdot 5\cdot 6\cdot 4$. Interpretation: two cases: 
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{1-digit}&\text{4-digit}&\text{2-digit}&\text{3-digit}\\
\hline
\text{even} \ (2 \  \text{options:} \ 4,8) & \text{even} \ (3 \ \text{options:} \ 0,2,4 \ \text{or} \ 8)& 6 \ \text{options}& 5 \ \text{options}\\
\text{odd} \ (3 \  \text{options:} \ 5,7,9)& \text{even} \ (4 \ \text{options:} \ 0,2,4, 8)& 6 \ \text{options}& 5 \ \text{options}\\
\end{array}$$
3) because there are $510$ odd and $540$ even numbers:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{4-digit}&\text{1-digit}&\text{2-digit}&\text{3-digit}\\
\hline
1 & 5 \ \text{options:} \ 4,5,7,8,9 & 6 \ \text{options} \ & 5 \ \text{options}\\
5& 4 \ \text{options:} \ 4,7,8,9 & 6 \ \text{options}& 5 \ \text{options}\\
7& 4 \ \text{options:} \ 4,5,8,9 & 6 \ \text{options}& 5 \ \text{options}\\
9& 4 \ \text{options:} \ 4,5,7,8 & 6 \ \text{options}& 5 \ \text{options}
\end{array}\\
\text{Hence:} \ 5\cdot 6\cdot 5+4\cdot 6\cdot 5+4\cdot 6\cdot 5+4\cdot 6\cdot 5=510.$$
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{4-digit}&\text{1-digit}&\text{2-digit}&\text{3-digit}\\
\hline
0 & 5 \ \text{options:} \ 4,5,7,8,9 & 6 \ \text{options} \ & 5 \ \text{options}\\
2& 5 \ \text{options:} \ 4,5,7,8,9 & 6 \ \text{options}& 5 \ \text{options}\\
4& 4 \ \text{options:} \ 5,7,8,9 & 6 \ \text{options}& 5 \ \text{options}\\
8& 4 \ \text{options:} \ 4,5,7,9 & 6 \ \text{options}& 5 \ \text{options}
\end{array}\\
\text{Hence:} \ 5\cdot 6\cdot 5+5\cdot 6\cdot 5+4\cdot 6\cdot 5+4\cdot 6\cdot 5=540.$$

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not merely half is because, by picking the thousands digit first, we restrict the ones digit in different ways: if we select an odd thousands digit (of which there are three), there are four legal choices for the ones digit, but if we select an even thousands digit (of which there are two), there are only three.

Which is to say, the number of numbers that can be formed is in fact $3\cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 + 2 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 3$.

Comment: Can you show that the sum of all 4-digit even and odd number that can be formed is equal to the total number of 4-digit number that can be formed using the given digits that is greater than 3000? (without repetition of digits)

Answer (score 0):

1. The first digit has to be at least $4$, this gives us five options. The rest simply can't repeat so by product rule there are $7\cdot 6\cdot 5$ options to complete the number. In total $7\cdot 6\cdot 5^2$ choices.
2. First digit is still at least $4$. There are two cases to consider.

If the first digit is odd (three choices), then there are four ways to pick the last digit. To avoid repetition in between there are in total $3\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot 5$ choices.

If the first digit is even (two choices), then there are three ways to pick the last digit. Avoiding repetition in between there are in total $2\cdot 3\cdot 6\cdot 5$ choices.

There is obviously no overlap between numbers starting with even/odd digit so one sums up the number of choices for the total.

Comment: Careful: no repetition is allowed here.

Comment: Sorry, you made some mistakes in 2. What if you let $8$ finish the number? Then you only have 4 choices to begin.

Comment: oh, you mean $8008$ counts as a repetition? I thought we're asked how many unique 4 digit numbers can be formed.

Comment: Also no repetition here.

Comment: Yes. We can only use a digit once to form a 4-digit number Sir.

Comment: @MRA I misunderstood assignment, I hope the solution is correct now.

Comment: 5*5*6*7 is the total number of 4-digit number greater than 3000. I tried to use the structure you share to find all the possible 4-digit odd number. The sum of all 4-digit even and odd number that can be formed is not equal to the total number of 4-digit number that can be formed using the given digits that is greater than 3000 (without repetition of digits)

Comment: @MRA you are right, if you mean what I wrote for 3. I misread something and later realised you were talking about something else. Curiously, there are twice as many odd-beginning numbers than there are even-beginning numbers.

Answer (score 0):

For your third question, to do that, you are assuming that there are equal number of odd and even number of $4$ digits number formed by those particular digits that are greater than $3000$. You have to justify if this assumption is valid.

For your second question. We need to pay attention to the first and the last digit.

If the first digit is even, there are $2$ choices. After using an even digit at the first place, you have two choices at the last position. $(2 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 3)$.

If the first digit is odd, there are $3$ choices. There are $3$ options at the last digit. $(3 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4)$